# Nginx deny IP's and setting custom 403 downloads a file?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-403, deny

I've attached my Nginx conf file for my default site which runs on Ubuntu.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. Main directory is `/usr/share/nginx/www` with the default file `index.php`
2. Restricting IP addresses for now until launch so only my IP's can view the site
3. For everyone else that attempts to visit the site, deny them, but display a custom 403 page which is `403.html` which is sitting in the `/usr/share/nginx/www` main directory

What happens though is when I visit the site from a different IP address (one that is denied access) it will load the 403.html page but download a file called "download". If I visit example.com/index.php it will download an index.php file.

Something isn't configured correctly but unsure what it is.

```
server {
        listen   80;


        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

                # restrict IP's
                allow 123.456.789.0;
                allow 123.456.789.1;
                deny all;
        }

        location = /403.html {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/www;
           allow all;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 403 /403.html;       

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
             # root /var/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

Comment: Check your mime types. You also need to move access restrictions to server block level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your deny rules from `location /` one level up, because now they are not applied to php requests.

```
server {
        listen   80;


        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php;

        server_name example.com;

        allow 123.456.789.0;
        allow 123.456.789.1;
        deny all;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        #....

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to implement this now and let you know how it goes. Will accept your answer once confirmed.